# Cannot delete file - No such file or directory

Tags: linux, windows, file-permissions, ntfs, rm

## Issue:

I have a file sitting on an NTFS partition that I am unable to delete or move. I am able to view the file. This is also preventing me from reading that directory while inside Windows. I get the error; 
"The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable" when trying to access this directory while inside Windows.

```
[root@ziggurat var]# ls -al .piw\?PageNum\=0 
-rw-r--r-- 0 ttucker root 2016 Jan 28 08:56 '.piw?PageNum=0'

[root@ziggurat var]# rm -i .p*
rm: remove regular file '.piw?PageNum=0'? y
rm: cannot remove '.piw?PageNum=0': No such file or directory

[root@ziggurat var]# mv .piw\?PageNum\=0 derp
mv: cannot move '.piw?PageNum=0' to 'derp': No such file or directory
```

If I try to edit the file with `vim` I see `".piw?PageNum=0" [Permission Denied]` at the bottom left.

If I try to modify the permissions I get the following error:

```
[root@ziggurat var]# chmod 777 .piw\?PageNum\=0 
chmod: cannot access '.piw?PageNum=0': Input/output error
```

## More information:

This is a second drive which contains one partition. The partition was created inside Windows 10. This partition does not contain my `Windows C Drive` - this drive is completely separate from my Linux root and Windows oot partitions.

```
[root@ziggurat var]# pwd
/mnt/storage/ttucker/var

[root@ziggurat var]# df -h /mnt/storage/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       932G  197G  736G  22% /mnt/storage

[root@ziggurat var]# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 91985B34-E4D8-4F7B-ABF4-7F2E27482077

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Microsoft basic data
```

## Even more information:

While inside Windows I am not able to switch into the `var` directory. I receive the message: `The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.` I am able to view and modify anywhere else in the drive.

The file was initially created, likely, with a botched `wget` command.

The file is there and I can `cat` it to `STDOUT`. The contents are HTML from a US Patent webpage.

```
[root@ziggurat var]# cat .piw\?PageNum\=0 
<!-- PageNum=0  -->
<!-- NumPages=0 -->
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Patent Images</TITLE></HEAD> 
  <BODY TOPMARGIN="0" leftmargin="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" >
... clipped for brevity ...
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is the OS and ntfs-3g info:

```
[root@ziggurat var]# pacman -Ss ntfs
extra/ntfs-3g 2016.2.22-1 [installed]
    NTFS filesystem driver and utilities

[root@ziggurat var]# uname -a
Linux ziggurat 4.9.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 26 09:22:26 CET 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## Final note:

I also tried running umount'ing the drive and running `ntfsfix` on it. This did not help.

Thanks!

---

## Update

I `chmod 777`'d the `var` dir... Then ran `chown -R root:root var`, received this error: `chown: changing ownership of 'var/.piw?PageNum=0': Input/output error` ... then ... looking in the dir:

```
[root@ziggurat var]# ls -ltra
ls: cannot access '.piw?PageNum=0': Input/output error
total 3116333
-????????? ? ?       ?             ?            ? '.piw?PageNum=0'
-rw-r--r-- 1 ttucker root     250910 Jan 28 08:56  0.pdf
....
```

Ugh... I think the drive is just `jacked` <-- technical term

---

## Second Update:

After running the `chown` on the directory mentioned above I then rebooted into Windows. During the Windows load it stated that it was `checking the drive for consistency` (or something of that language) Anywho... it works now. The file is gone and I am able to read it in Windows.

## Additional information which may be helpful to others:

I have two drives with the same files on them; an internal backup drive and an external backup drive. Both are NTFS and both `var` dirs could not be accessed in Windows. After resolving the issue with the internal drive I found that deleting the "goofy" named files resolved the issue on the external drive as well. Example:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       2016 Dec 31 22:31 '.piw?PageNum=0'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8379 Dec 31 22:32 '.piw?PageNum=0&docid=01111111&IDKey=DE3F91CB19BB%0D%0A&HomeUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpatft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect1%3DPTO1%2526Sect2%3DHITOFF%2526d%3DPALL%2526p%3D1%2526u%3D%25252Fnetahtml%25252FPTO%25252Fsrchnum.htm%2526r%3D1%25'
```

For some reason, perhaps because I did not run `ntfsfix`, on the external drive I was able to just delete those two "problem files" and then read that directory in Windows.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a combination of a funny file name:

`.piw?PageNum=0&docid=01111111&IDKey=DE3F91CB19BB%0D%0A&HomeUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpatft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect1%3DPTO1%2526Sect2%3DHITOFF%2526d%3DPALL%2526p%3D1%2526u%3D%25252Fnetahtml%25252FPTO%25252Fsrchnum.htm%2526r%3D1%25`

... and then an `ntfsfix` ...

Eventual solution was messing around with file perms and ownership, then a restart into Windows (which checked the disk for consistency).